# GitHub Pages won't load fonts

Tags: reactjs, github, font-awesome

I set up a react [portfolio](https://danielmarostica.github.io/) on github, and [here](https://github.com/danielmarostica/danielmarostica.github.io)'s the build folder.

The problem is: I have to alter the chunk.css file, after the `npm run build`, from `url(danielmarostica.github.io/static/media/Montserrat-Regular.ee653992.ttf)` to `url(../media/Montserrat-Regular.ee653992.ttf)`, otherwise github won't load fonts. Why is that? If you access the link directly, you can even download the font.

How can I automatically build the website with the correct path?

[Original source files.](https://github.com/ashutosh1919/masterPortfolio/)

Comment: `url(daniel...)` will load from (if you're on `https://danielmarostica.github.io/`), `https://danielmarostica.github.io/daniel...`

Comment: Damn?? Thank you! LOL

Answer (score 0):

The url MUST start with https:// in order to work.

Thanks to @heretic-monkey.